# Building task scheduling environment for training DQN agent

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, environment, reinforcement-learning, dqn

description:
I have a dataset which includes task requirements, nodes specifications, and resources usage. I need to use this data to train DQN agent to get optimal task scheduling. How can I build the task scheduling environment for training the agent on this data.

question:
How can I build a custom environment for training RL agent based on  real dataset?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.